# Binding controls inside the template Column

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatemplate, autocompletebox, datatemplateselector

I have a datagrid with 3 columns. The columns are `Property, Operator, Value`. These are about the documents stored in our database. The values of the `Property` and `Operator` columns are defined from an enumeration in the business objects.

I have the following class to bind the DataGrid:

```
public class DocumentProperty
{
    public SearchProperties SearchProperty { get; set; }
    public SearchOperator Operator { get; set; }
    public string SearchValue { get; set; }
}
```

The first two properties are enums. I have bound the observable collection of the above class to my datagrid. All the columns are template columns.The first two column have a `CellEditTemplate` with a combobox defined in them. I have bound the enums using the object data providers. The third column is a template column and it is loaded using the Template Selector. The reason for this is to enable load different controls based on the property selected in the first column:

[image]

Also I have a combobox selection changed event to load the controls dynamically (explicitly set the datatemplate for the column) in the third column and set the datasources (for AutoCompleteBox). The above approach is working fine when the grid is initially loaded with setting of Allow Add Row set as true. I can able to get the loaded controls values into the object (using the selected Item in AutoCompleteBox, etc).

But I am facing issues in the above input is stored as search filter and retrieved. While retrieval I am unable to bind the value of the properties to the dynamically loaded controls. I have tried various events of the DataGrid (RowLoading, Loaded, SelectedCellChanged,etc).

Finally I am able to set the value of the controls in the template selector. But when I see the screen, it is showing a blank content (for autocompleteBoxes and comboBoxes). Could anybody suggest How can I re-bind the dynamic controls with the SearchValue?

More Details:

The content of the above grid is stored as observable collection of DocumentProperty. The values of the object is stroed in a database table as XML. When the user is logged in again the content of the XML is converted to Observable collection of DocumentProperty and binded to the grid again. Here I facing a issue that if I place a cell template and put the textblock inside that I can bind the SearchValue property without any issues. But I am stroing the IDs of binded object in the search value property. So the textblock in the binded grid will alway shows the ID.

As I want to show the corresponding name of the Tempalte,Docment,Owner etc in the AutoCompleteBoxes above. So I make the column as DataTemplate column with the cell Template Selector.

Comment: `But I am facing issues in the above input is stored as search filter and retrieved.` i don't see a `search filter` on your UI.. nor do i see your search filter code.

Comment: I have provided more details in the above description.

Comment: I will also check whether the ComboBox selction changed event is firing after the template selector fired. In this case there is chance that the Template selector content repalced by the ComboBox (first column) selection changed event.

Comment: your "More Details:" section still didn't say anything about a search filter. show more code if necessary